# Cache image thumbnails in flex TileList control

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I have a flex TileList to which I load a bunch of images.

When the tile list is scrolled up and down, it does fresh requests for all the images even though they were loaded previously.

Is there a way to stop this behavior and let the TileList control keep its previously loaded images?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flex does not provide you with native caching of images. It loads them afresh. You will have to write your own cache (a linked list of images). Two references you should look at with sample implementation for image caching:

- [SuperImage](http://www.quietlyscheming.com/blog/2007/01/23/some-thoughts-on-doubt-on-flex-as-the-best-option-orhow-i-made-my-flex-images-stop-dancing/) -- I've used this and this works well
- [ImageCache](http://thanksmister.com/?tag=titlelist)

Comment: Thanks! super image seems to be the solution!

Comment: +1 for ImageCache, looked like our app had a visit from the performance fairy.